# Re: Kurso de Esperanto results

Tags: learning, resources, course

Just finished [Kurso de Esperanto](https://www.kurso.com.br/) on Sunday w/o a tutor. Want to know how does one go about obtaining a complete hard copy of your results.

Comment: Welcome to this Esperanto forum! Can you specify what course where?

Comment: Yes it’s “Kurso de Esperanto”.

Comment: Are you referring to the one available at https://www.kurso.com.br, @Ani?

Comment: @das-g Yes. Kurso.com.br. I completed it a couple weeks ago and was wondering has anyone else completed it and how one would go about getting their full results.

Comment: @Juha Metsäkallas Kurso.com.br is the course I finished a couple weeks ago and was wondering how I would obtain my full results.

Comment: Mi ne scias ekzakte kion vi celas per *get their full results* sed tiu estas [memlerna materialo](https://www.kurso.com.br/korektanto.php?eo), mi dubas ke tiu eblo jam ekzistu. Sed iu povus ĝin aldoni! Vi povas kontroli la [fontan kodon](https://github.com/antono/kurso-de-esperanto/tree/forko) (aŭ peti al iu tion fari).

Comment: @Eduardo Trápani Mi dankas vin pro via helpo.